# Redefinition of pH

Tags: discussion

Fundamental SI units like the kilogram and the mole change definition this year. We should not stop there but redefine some quantities describing aqueous solutions of acids and bases as well.

**A better scale for acidity and basicity of aqueous solutions**

There are two aspects of the current definition of $\mathrm{pH}$ that are strange: First, neutral $\mathrm{pH}$ is at 7 (what is so special about 7?) at room temperature. Secondly, at a different temperature, it is not even 7. A new measure of acidity of a solution would be based on the excess of $\ce{H+}$ over $\ce{OH-}$:

$$\text{pHx} = -\log\sqrt{\frac{[\ce{H+}]}{[\ce{OH-}]}}$$

Pure water has a $\mathrm{pHx}$ of 0 independent of temperature. One molar solutions of strong acids and strong bases have a $\mathrm{pHx}$ of -7 and 7, respectively, at room temperature. A change in one unit of $\mathrm{pHx}$ still is a factor 10 in hydronium and hydroxide, just like for $\mathrm{pH}$.

**More equity for hydronium and hydroxide**

Acid dissociation reactions are currently written like this:

$$\ce{AH + H2O <=> H3O+ + A-}$$

This suggests the only thing an acid does is to raise the hydronium ion concentration. When an acid is added to a solution, however, not only does the hydronium concentration increase but the hydroxide concentration decreases at the same time. Depending which of these is the major species, you are more interested in the former or the latter. Here is a better way to write what happens when an acid reacts with water:

$$\ce{AH + 1/2 OH- <=> A- + 1/2 H3O+}$$

The equilibrium constant expression for this is

$$K_\ce{AB} = \frac{[\ce{A-}][\ce{H3O+}]^{1/2}}{[\ce{AH}][\ce{OH-}]^{1/2}}$$

This would supersede $K_\ce{A}$ and $K_\ce{B}$.

**New formulas for new quantities**

Of course we have to newly derive ways to calculate the $\mathrm{pHx}$ of a strong acid, strong base, weak acid, weak base and buffer. The results are summarized below:

$$
\begin{align}
&\text{Strong acid} &\quad \text{pHx} &= -\log [\text{strong acid}] - 7 \\
&\text{Strong base} &\quad \text{pHx} &= +\log [\text{strong base}] + 7 \\
&\text{Weak acid} &\quad \text{pHx} &= \frac{1}{2}(\text{p}K_\mathrm{ab} -\log [\text{weak acid}] - 7) \\
&\text{Weak base} &\quad \text{pHx} &= \frac{1}{2}(\text{p}K_\mathrm{ab} + \log [\text{weak base}] + 7) \\
&\text{Buffer} &\quad \text{pHx} &= \text{p}K_\mathrm{ab} + \log \frac{[\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{AH}]}
\end{align}
$$

As you see, the redefinition makes it easier to work with bases, introducing more symmetry into the calculations.

**Conversions**

What do you do when comparing old-style with new-style acid/base definitions? Here is a handy list of conversions:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{pH} &= 7 + \text{pHx} \\
\text{pOH} &= 7 - \text{pHx} \\
\text{p}K_\mathrm{a} &= 7 + \text{p}K_\mathrm{ab} \\
\text{p}K_\mathrm{b} &= 7 - \text{p}K_\mathrm{ab}
\end{align}
$$

**When is the switch?**

The new definitions will become effective today, April $1^\text{st}$ 2019.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. This should be the way going forward, definitely. Is IUPAC paying any attention?

Comment: @orthocresol It seems like IUPAC is already denoting acidity of some solution X in an electrochemical cell with $\mathrm{pHx}$ ([strangely formatted PDF](http://media.iupac.org/publications/analytical_compendium/Cha03sec4.pdf))

Comment: Hmmm, not sure, but I have a feeling this would be more suited on main, as a self Q&A. While it does in a way affect the site in general, it is not really something that would be (/become) policy, so it is not really about the site.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I have a feeling April Fool's is rather more suitable for meta :D

Comment: @Mithoron I had a feeling someone would vote to close it  on main (not clear what is being asked, asking for personal opinion etc.), so I posted it here. I also did not want to confuse any confused learners further.

Comment: This could have gone one further, becoming hot nitric acid, going virial on the interwebz; and possibly never to be gotten rid of again. O.ô

Comment: I hope I dodged that bullet (unless IUPAC shows interest, then I would be all in of course).

Comment: Well, it **has** made the "hot meta posts" list, at least for the moment. I'm sure there will be more like me who click over from the main site... ;-)